# Flare ItemVisualisation

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Using [the latest Flare build](https://github.com/fzzr-/Flare) originally built by prefuse, I am trying to get an indent field like the one in Layouts seen [here](http://flare.prefuse.org/demo). I am working with a list of objects that I pull from Google Firebase. While I can put them on a graph just fine and compare one and other values I can't find instructions on the different layouts. I am about to study the docs but I wanted to know if there was anything else out there I could reference.

---

Edit:
http://flare.prefuse.org/api/flare/vis/operator/layout/Layout.html I have found the general layouts here. However I only am able to show 1 or two circles unless I do AxisLayout.

For reference, my data pulled from firebase is something like this.

An array of objects.
Each object has properties name, sales, date, active and such.

I want it to act like the example above and show the item name in each circle. Then when the user clicks the circle he is able to show the properties of the item.

---

Edit: I was able to find an article on it, but after hours of constructing my data around his set format, I am not able to mock it entirely.
http://simon.oconnorlamb.com/ria/2012/03/visualising-data-with-flare/

---

Edit: To go into detail:

When I pull from my json list from Google Firebase I parse it so that it puts the items in referencable categories. All of which go into an array to mock the tutorial I linked above. I am trying to mock the structure as close as possible.

```
private function handleDataRead(e:DatabaseEvent):void 
    {
        var trueDataArray:Array = new Array();

        //Extract manufacturers.
        var manufacturers:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();
        for each (var item:Object in e.data)
        {
            if (manufacturers.indexOf(item.Manufacturer) == -1)
            {
                manufacturers.push(item.Manufacturer);
                //Example:  {type:'Manufacturer',id:'0',name:'Company A'}
                trueDataArray.push( {type:'manufacturer',
                id:manufacturers.indexOf(item.Manufacturer).toString(),
                name:item.Manufacturer});
            }
        }

        //Extract Item Name
        var itemNames:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();
        for each (var item:Object in e.data)
        {
            if (itemNames.indexOf(item.ItemName) == -1)
            {
                itemNames.push(item.ItemName);
                var idValue:String = new String(itemNames.indexOf(item.ItemName) + (manufacturers.length - 1) +1);
                trueDataArray.push( {type:'item',
                id:idValue,
                name:item.ItemName,
                manufacturer:manufacturers.indexOf(item.Manufacturer).toString()} );
            }
        }


        //Extract property 1
        var mlCount:Vector.<int> = new Vector.<int>();
        for each (var item:Object in e.data)
        {
            if (item.hasOwnProperty("ML"))
            {
                if (mlCount.indexOf(item.ML) == -1)
                {
                    mlCount.push(item.ML);
                    var idValue:String = new String(mlCount.indexOf(item.ML) + (itemNames.length - 1) + (manufacturers.length - 1) +1);
                    trueDataArray.push({type:'mL',
                    id:idValue,
                    name:(item.ML as int).toString(),
                    item:itemNames.indexOf(item.ItemName).toString()});
                }
            }               
        }

        //Extract another property 
        var mgCount:Vector.<int> = new Vector.<int>();
        for each (var item:Object in e.data)
        {
            if (item.hasOwnProperty("MG"))
            {
                if (mgCount.indexOf(item.MG) == -1)
                {
                    mgCount.push(item.MG);
                    var idValue:String = new String(mgCount.indexOf(item.MG) + mlCount.indexOf(item.ML) + (itemNames.length - 1) + (manufacturers.length - 1) +1);
                    trueDataArray.push({type:'mG',
                    id:idValue,
                    name:(item.MG as int).toString(),
                    mL:mlCount.indexOf(item.ML).toString()});
                }
            }

        }
```

The result looks like this.

```
[
   {
      "name":"Company A",
      "type":"manufacturer",
      "id":"0"
   },
   {
      "name":"Company B",
      "type":"manufacturer",
      "id":"1"
   },
   {
      "name":"Company C",
      "type":"manufacturer",
      "id":"2"
   },
   {
      "name":"Company D",
      "type":"manufacturer",
      "id":"3"
   },
   {
      "name":"Company E",
      "type":"manufacturer",
      "id":"4"
   },
   {
      "type":"manufacturer",
      "id":"5"
   },
... //So on
   {
      "manufacturer":"0",
      "name":"Item Name 1",
      "type":"item",
      "id":"18"
   },
   {
      "manufacturer":"0",
      "name":"Item Name 2",
      "type":"item",
      "id":"19"
   },
   {
      "manufacturer":"0",
      "name":"Item Name 3",
      "type":"item",
      "id":"20"
   },
   {
      "manufacturer":"0",
      "name":"Item Name 4",
      "type":"item",
      "id":"21"
 ...//So on
   {
      "name":"60",
      "item":"0",
      "type":"mL",
      "id":"195"
   },
   {
      "name":"100",
      "item":"5",
      "type":"mL",
      "id":"196"
   },
   {
      "name":"120",
      "item":"36",
      "type":"mL",
      "id":"197"
   },
   {
      "name":"30",
      "item":"100",
      "type":"mL",
      "id":"198"
   }
   ...//and so forth
]
```

When I pass this to my function to create the nodes and edges (that I again based off the blog in the link above)

```
    public function buildTree(arr:Array):Data
    {
        var d:Data = new Data(true);
        //Keyed lookup for easy edge addition in step 2
        var nodeLookup:Object = {};
        var row:Object;
        var ns:NodeSprite;
        //Step 1: Add all rows of data;
        for each(row in arr){
            ns = d.addNode(row);
            nodeLookup[row.id] = ns;
        }
        //Step 2: Add edges
        for each(ns in d.nodes){
            if(ns.data.hasOwnProperty('manufacturer')){
                d.addEdgeFor(nodeLookup[ns.data.manufacturer],ns);
            }
            else if(ns.data.hasOwnProperty('item')){
                d.addEdgeFor(nodeLookup[ns.data.item],ns);
            }
            else if(ns.data.hasOwnProperty('mL')){
                d.addEdgeFor(nodeLookup[ns.data.mL],ns);
            }
        }
        return d;
    }
```

and construct it

```
        data = buildTree(trueDataArray);
        sourceTree = new ItemVisualisation(data);


        sourceTree.bounds = new Rectangle(10, 10, 550, 550);
        sourceTree.x = 20;
        sourceTree.y = 20;
        addChild(sourceTree);

        sourceTree.operators.add(new IndentedTreeLayout());
        sourceTree.operators.add(new ShapeEncoder("data.type"));
        sourceTree.operators.add(new ColorEncoder("data.type", Data.NODES, "lineColor", ScaleType.CATEGORIES));
        sourceTree.data.nodes.setProperties({fillColor:0, lineWidth:2});
        sourceTree.update();
```

I get the following..
[image]

I almost have this down but I don't know what I am doing wrong. Everything seems to be as it should in relation.

---

Edit: It seems that the nodes may be linking properly with each other however this is not the layout I desire. I cannot get any other layouts to work either.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
trueDataArray.push({type:'root', id:0, name:'rootname'});
```

I was able to solve this problem by binding everything to 1 node. I was having some trouble listing anything beyond two steps but that is beyond the requirement of my project.
[image]